How to pass parameters into reusable workflows?
I am using reusable workflow in GitHub Actions. Any idea why this workflow job in my feature.yml file:
  my-job:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    uses: my-org/my-repo/.github/workflows/reusable.yml@v1.0.0
    with:
      app-command: synth
      app-args: -c xpiKeyPath=/my/apikey 

would give an error like this:

The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/feature.yml (Line: 10,
Col: 5): Unexpected value 'uses' .github/workflows/feature.yml (Line:
10, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'with'


runs-on and uses are mutually exclusive - the reusable workflow is the one that defines the runner for those jobs.

Check here how to call a reusable workflow, you need to remove the runs-on, for example:
jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      config-path: .github/labeler.yml
    secrets:
      envPAT: ${{ secrets.envPAT }}

